# Is There any onPermissionChangeListener for android

Tags: android, permissions, listener

So in my app Im use push notifications and I store the notification status of the users (true|false, if they have enabled notifications or not).

But lets say that the user is using the app and then he goes to the settings while the app open and changes the notifications permissions or while he is using the app a notification comes and he decided from the notification menu to block them.

Is there any listener in order to change the notification status at that that in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can check notification status using following code

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()
```

Comment: Yes I've seen that, but do I trigger that right after the user has blocked notifications?

Comment: no there is no listener for get notification change status

Comment: So the only way to get that is if I trigger the code or if I check the permissions for example when I open the app?

Comment: yes when you open the app please check notification status using above code